# Test a MNIST number

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

after trained and evaluated a model, I am trying to feed the model with a MNIST test image :

[image]

The function Logits fails. X_new_scaled is a 784 long array, scaled from 0.01 to 0.99XXX What does the method logits.eval expect to reiceve? what is the correct way to pass the array?

Comment: Please paste your code and error in your question instead of linking to an image, this makes it easier to search for content.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a duplicate of [TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664985/typeerror-unhashable-type-numpy-ndarray-tensorflow)

The point is that you use X twice:

```
X = mnist["data"]
```

And

```
Z = logits.eval(feed_dict={X: X_new_scaled})
```

So the problem is not X_new_scaled, the problem is that the key of your feed_dict, being X is not a tensor but a a numpy.ndarray.

Comment: Thank fo your reply. I ' m new in Tensorflow. Can you write a correct version example of this operation?